# ViewPager how to interrupt scroll

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have one ViewPager and two adapters.
I travel between adapters by swiping out of last page(1st adapter) and out of first page(2nd adapter).

Everything works well. Though, when I start scrolling, for example, out of last page of 1st adapter, I get data replaced so I have new tabs and pages, BUT my scroll continues. Just that last page is replaced with first page of 2nd adapter. Now its like I'm scrolling from that first page.

I would like to stop that scroll once new adapter appeared. Is that possible?

Upds. solved by disabling touches and then enabling them when touch is released.

```
`vp.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        vpContainer.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> false}
    }
    true 
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `setOnTouchListener()` and return `true` when you want to stop the scrolling - so when you switched data.

Anyway, your implementation is flacky IMHO. Also a bit of code could have helped.

Comment: Dont know about flacky but good-looking.
It worked man, tho except returning true, I've added condition to return false when ACTION_UP detected), to make it accept touches again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

when you return the "true" value on touch listener, view pager would not scroll anymore:

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);
```

so you could customize the view pager setOnTouchListener to get your desired behavior:

```
  mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (someCriteria){
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```